# ¿Como consigo que no se bloquee la app mientras hay un proceso en segundo plano?

Tags: android-studio, background, bloqueo

Estoy creando una pequeña app en AndroidStudio que hace una conexion con un servidor(que de momento es el mismo PC) para enviar y recibir un objeto, el proceso lo he metido dentro de un AssyncTask, y dentro del doInBackground he metido el codigo, pero durante el proceso la aplicacion se bloquea, como lo puedo solucionar?
He encontrado soluciones para runnable y callable, pero necesito enviar y recibir un objeto.

```
public class Comunicaciones extends AsyncTask<Message, Integer, Message> {

    private Object input;
    private int PORT = 5050;
    private String IP = "192.168.1.33"; //PC
    
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.d("INFO: ", "Empieza assync");
    }

    @Override
    protected Message doInBackground(Message... messages) {

        synchronized (this){
            try {
                Socket sk = new Socket(IP, PORT);
                Message message = messages[0];
                Log.d("INFO: ", "ENVIANDO COMANDO: " + message.getCommand());

                ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(sk.getOutputStream());
                os.writeObject(message);

                ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(sk.getInputStream());

                try {
                    input = is.readObject();                
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.d("INFO: ", "RESPUESTA: " + ((Message) input).getToken());

                sk.close();
                is.close();
                os.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            return (Message) input;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Message message) {
        super.onPostExecute(message);        
        Log.d("INFO: ", "Acaba assync");
    }
```

El proceso es correcto, se envia y se recibe el objeto, la llamada la hago desde otra activity con el siguiente codigo:

```
private boolean checkTokenOnline() {

        String respuesta = "";        

        String sendMessage = user.getText().toString() + "¬" + password.getText().toString();
        Forat19.Message message = new Message(null, "Loggin", sendMessage, null);

        Log.d("INFO:", "ENVIO: " + sendMessage);

        Comunicaciones com = new Comunicaciones();

        try {
            respuesta = com.execute(message).get().getToken();
            Log.d("INFO: ", respuesta);

        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (respuesta.equals("ValidToken")) {
            return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Si usas Java, es correcto uses un `AsyncTask` pero en este caso es innecesario usar `synchronized` dentro del método `doInBackground()` del `AsyncTask`, seguramente este es el problema, cambia tu método a:

```
  @Override
    protected Message doInBackground(Message... messages) {

       // synchronized (this){
            try {
                Socket sk = new Socket(IP, PORT);
                Message message = messages[0];
                Log.d("INFO: ", "ENVIANDO COMANDO: " + message.getCommand());

                ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(sk.getOutputStream());
                os.writeObject(message);

                ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(sk.getInputStream());

                try {
                    input = is.readObject();                
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.d("INFO: ", "RESPUESTA: " + ((Message) input).getToken());

                sk.close();
                is.close();
                os.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            return (Message) input;
       // }

    }
```

Cuando se usa `synchronized` solo un hilo puede estar ejecutándose en un mismo momento y este no es el objetivo del AsyncTask.

---

**Actualización:**

Comentas también que llamas el `AsyncTask` de esta forma:

```
respuesta = com.execute(message).get()
```

**El problema es el uso de [.get()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#get()), ya que bloquea el hilo principal hasta obtener la respuesta del `AsyncTask`.**

La respuesta del proceso que realiza el `AsyncTask` la debes obtener dentro de `onPostExecute()` o bien puedes [implementar un Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9274336/250260) para obtener la respuesta.

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta pero incluso quitando el `synchronized` sigue haciendo lo mismo...

Comment: @ChimoSirgado no debería bloquearse, precisamente para eso es el AsyncTask, como lo estas llamando desde tu código?

Comment: Lo llamo desde un metodo de otra clase...
``respuesta = com.execute(message).get().getToken``
Lo tienes entero en el codigo de arriba...

Comment: El problema es que usas  .get(), aquí esperará hasta obtener la respuesta, no debes usar este método para que funcione normalmente el AsyncTask como un proceso asincronico., revisa mi actualización.

Comment: Tienes razón, el problema era ese, ahora me toca encontrar una alternativa, investigaré sobre el callback que comentas... Muchas gracias!!